# WPF - Making DragDrop and ManipulationEnabled co-exist

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, drag-and-drop, multi-touch

I have a somewhat unusual design problem in a WPF touch application.

I have a **UserControl** that holds an image, which I allow the user to freely move, resize, and rotate around the touch surface using multitouch by setting:

> isManipulationEnabled = true

and then hooking up events for `ManipulationStarting`, `ManipulationDelta`, and `ManipulationCompleted`.

This is all good and works perfectly, but now I would like to add the ability for a user to drag this control into the `WrapPanel` on another control, which has a list of image files, and add this image to the list.

I tried using `DragDrop` events by calling `DragDrop.DoDragDrop()` on the `ManipulationDelta` event, but it locks the UI and the control until a drop occurs, which is not what I want.

Is there any way to properly do this without writing my own hit-testing code?  I'm using WPF 4.0 and .NET 4.5 on VS 2013, and I'm not sure if the Surface SDK would help me in this case (nor could I properly install/load it to VS2013)

Comment: Does your userControl derive from `Thumb`?

Comment: It is not.  It's a Usercontrol with a main image and a few buttons attached to it.  Would using Thumb help?

Edit: looking over the WPF description of Thumb, it doesn't sound like what I'm looking for

Comment: Thumb has the ability of DragStarted, DragDelta and DragCompleted (all events). I once used this method to solve my problem.

Comment: I need the ability to Drop my usercontrol into another one.  I am handling the dragging around/resizing/rotating part using Manipulation events.  Would using a Thumb allow Dropping and translate/resize/rotate?

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution:  Use [VisualTreeHelper.HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and call the HitTest in the event handler for ManipulationDelta, and then use your own logic for handling the drag over operation.  Use ManipulationCompleted event to check the hit test again to complete the drop